# Difference between Option[String] = None and Option[String] in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I have started learning Scala and going through the code (case classes and other stuff) in my project.

I see a case class defined like this:

```
case class Test(firstName: Option[String] = None, lastName: Option[String])
```

I have few questions on the above case class:

1. What is the difference between `Option[String] = None` and `Option[String]`?
2. What is the correct usage, when should we use `Option[String] = None` and `Option[String]`?

Answer (score 5):

The *"regex"* for a parameter is something like this: `name: type (= defaultValue)` - Note that the default value part is *optional*.

Thus `firstName: Option[String] = None` means the parameter is named **firstName** and it is of type **Option[String]** and its default value is a **None** *(also remember the Option type is used to explain that a value may exist or not. And that **None** means it doesn't exist)*.

Both are correct depending on the context, in this case, this class can be used like:

```
Test(lastName = None)
// res: Test = Test(None,None) - A person without names.

Test(lastName = Some("Mejia"))
// res: Test = Test(None,Some(Mejia)) - A person with just its last name, which it is "Mejia".

Test(firstName = Some("Luis"), lastName = Some("Mejia"))
// res: Test = Test(Some(Luis),Some(Mejia)) - A person whose first name is "Luis" and its last name is "Mejia".

Test(firstName = Some("Luis"), lastName = None)
// res: Test = Test(Some(Luis),None) - A person with just its first name, which it is "Luis".
```

Note that I always have to specify its last name because it doesn't have a default value.